# Applying tf.abs() on multidimensional tensor (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

This should be super simple but I cannot find the right way to do it:

I have a tensor with shape (1, 1, 1024, 66) and I want to apply the operation tf.abs() on all values.
Doing tf.abs(tensor) gives the error:

```
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

tf.abs() does not have a parameter to specify the dimension.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually a different one. My tensor was not shape (1,1,1024,66), but the tensor was shape (1,1024,66) inside of a python list with length 1.

Doing `tf.abs(tensor[0])` did the job.